# Shaka Player is showing error Shaka Error MANIFEST.HLS_AES_128_ENCRYPTION_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: shaka

I have intergrated Google Shaka Player in my project for DRM/Non DRM videos.
Js Used https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/shaka-player/3.3.1/shaka-player.ui.debug.min.js
Its showing this error **Shaka Error MANIFEST.HLS_AES_128_ENCRYPTION_NOT_SUPPORTED**

Comment: When do you see this error?

Comment: And what's your question about this? Without sharing any code, it's impossible to tell you why this error happens or how to fix it